# Drag gesture on SwiftUI Buttons for complete task

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

Newbiew here in SwiftUI.
I'd like to do some buttons in SwiftUI with drag gesture(complete and delete) for my first portfolio project, a ToDoList App.
When they swipe right, to get them into CompleteVC and when you swipe left to delete item.

I would like them to be like that:

[First TaskVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHJi6.jpg)

[Save swipe right and save it in CompleteVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmMSZ.jpg)

This is my source code for ContentView, for CompleteVC I didn't made it yet:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var taskStore = TaskStore()
    @State var newToDo : String = ""
    
    var searchBar : some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Enter in a new task", text: self.$newToDo)
            Button(action: self.addNewToDo, label: {
                Text("Add New")
            })
        }
    }
    
    func addNewToDo() {
        taskStore.tasks.append(Task(id: String(taskStore.tasks.count + 1), toDoItem: newToDo))
        self.newToDo = ""
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                searchBar.padding()
                List {
                    ForEach(self.taskStore.tasks) { task in
                        Text(task.toDoItem)
                    }.onMove(perform: self.move)
                        .onDelete(perform: self.delete)
                }.navigationBarTitle("Tasks")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            }
        }
    }
    func move(from source : IndexSet, to destination : Int) {
        taskStore.tasks.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets : IndexSet) {
        taskStore.tasks.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your deployment target iOS 15+?

Comment: check out [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-custom-swipe-action-buttons-to-a-list-row)